# Ending A Session, Redirect to Another Page

Tags: php, session, redirect, logout

I am trying to redirect to another page upon breaking a session and destroying session variables.

Here is my code to logout:

```
<?php

_$SESSION['signin'] = null;

session_destroy();

header("Location: /index.php");

?>
```

I thought this was quite straight forward, however it simply stays on the logout.php page, and does not get redirected to the index page.

I assume his has something to do with destroying the session, kind of like an "exit" in php.

How can I go about redirecting then though?

Comment: if you comment out the `session_destroy()` will the redirect work properly?

Comment: unfortunately it appears that part of my school server is down at the moment. but I can tell you that I have used the `_$SESSION['signin']` variable in other operations before logout, so its there. And same with the header function, I've used it in other pages as well and it works as well.

Comment: If `_$SESSION` isn't a typo, it could be a parse error.

Comment: If not what G-Nugget points out (OP might wanna edit that) maybe it is due to headers already having been sent?.  Whoops.  See the answer below.  Good catch G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you appear to heave a simple syntax error in your first line:

WAS:

`_$SESSION['signin'] = null;`

It should be:

`$_SESSION['signin'] = null;`

**NOTE:** You probably have error messages suppressed/hidden.  When in development, you should have them enabled, you would have figured out this error very easily.

Comment: wow. can't believe I didn't see that. Thats what I get for trying to program while the debugger on the server is down